# Adding string to the end of a url

Tags: html

This might sound like a stupid question but just trying to learn something here.
Whats the difference with adding a string parameter to the end of the url using **&** or **?**

```
http://dd.bmpss.com/guide?id=63236
or
http://dd.bmpss.com/guide&id=63236
```

When I use & it breaks the loading of the page which is another issue but I just wanted to know what the advantages of using either symbol and what either symbol did.

Thanks,

Comment: The `?` character starts the query string, while the `&` character separate each supplied value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage of using `?` over `&` is that it works.

`?` separates your query string from the rest of the URL, and `&` separates parameters inside your query string.

Probably you should read [more about URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

`?` is use if you have to pass a variable from page to page and use `&` if you have many variables to pass.